# How can I eliminate prompts and dialog boxes in Emacs and enable auto-saving?

Tags: emacs

I never want to answer a prompt that asks me to save changes.

Whenever I close Emacs, I'm bombarded with dialog boxes and prompts. How can I avoid them and make Emacs automatically save all unsaved changes?

Also, how can I avoid the prompt when I close a single buffer with <kbd>C-k</kbd> and make Emacs automatically save the changes?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the prompts for saving files when quitting Emacs, you may pass a prefix argument to `C-x C-c`, i.e., quit with `C-u C-x C-c`.

Alternatively, add the following code to your `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c")
                #'(lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (save-buffers-kill-terminal t)))
```

to quit without prompts using the usual `C-x C-c` keybinding.

Don't forget that at these prompts you may press `!` to save *all* files.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
(defun kill-buffer-no-query (&optional buffer)
  "Kill BUFFER without querying."
  (interactive)
  (unless buffer (setq buffer  (current-buffer)))
  (let ((kill-buffer-query-functions ())
        (buffer-save-without-query   t)
        (buffer-modified-p           (buffer-modified-p)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
               (kill-buffer buffer))
      (when (get-buffer buffer)
        (set-buffer-modified-p buffer-modified-p)))))
```